# flask_sqlalchemy create_all() fails silently in unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm writing unit tests for a REST API written in Flask with the flask_sqlalchemy extension. Because I have a number of model classes, I wrote a `TestCase` subclass to do the standard setUp/cleanUp of the test database. All my test classes inherit from this. Each test succeeds when run alone, but when I run more than one test in a single class, the second setUp() fails on the `self.db.session.commit()` (I'm trying to add an entry to the User table) because `self.db.create_all()` has (silently) failed to create any tables.
Here is my base test class, in the `__init__.py` of the test package:

```
import unittest

from .test_client import TestClient
from .. import create_app
from pdb import set_trace as DBG

class ApiTest(unittest.TestCase):
    default_username = 'fred'
    default_password = 'bloggs'
    db = None

    def setUp(self):
        try:
            self.app = create_app('testing')
            self.addCleanup(self.cleanUp)
            self.ctx = self.app.app_context()
            self.ctx.push()
            from .. import db
            self.db = db
            self.db.session.commit()
            self.db.drop_all(app=self.app)
            from ..models import User, Player, Team, Match, Game
            # self.app.logger.debug('drop_all())')
            self.db.create_all(app=self.app)
            # self.app.logger.debug('create_all())')
            user = User(user_name=self.default_username)
            user.password = self.default_password
            self.db.session.add(u)
            self.db.session.commit()
            self.client = TestClient(self.app, user.generate_auth_token(), '')
        except Exception, ex:
            self.app.logger.error("Error during setUp: %s" % ex)
            raise

    def cleanUp(self):
        try:
            self.db.session.commit()
            self.db.session.remove()
            self.db.drop_all(app=self.app)
            # self.app.logger.debug('drop_all())')
            self.ctx.pop()
        except Exception, ex:
            self.app.logger.error("Error during cleanUp: %s" % ex)
            raise
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here please?

EDIT: Added the code for `create_app()` as requested.

```
# chessleague/__init__.py
import os

from flask import Flask, g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager


from . import config


app = None
db = None  # The database, initialised in create_app()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.update(config.get_config(config_name))
    # if app.config['USE_TOKEN_AUTH']:
    #     from api.token import token as token_blueprint
    #     app.register_blueprint(token_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
    syslog_handler = SysLogHandler()
    syslog_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    app.logger.addHandler(syslog_handler)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    global db
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    from .models import User,Player,Game,Match,Team,Post
    db.create_all()
    from .api import api as api_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint, url_prefix='/chessleague')
    return app
```

`

Comment: You mentioned a problem with the `create_all` but haven't added how it is invoked. I suppose it's called in `create_app', can you add this function to your question for us to see?

Comment: `db.create_all()` does get called in the `setUp()` method above, but your question got me to look again at `create_app()` in the main package. It turns out that it also calls `db.create_all()`, as you guessed. I've added it to the question.

Comment: ... but AFAIK `create_all()` should be idempotent.

Comment: There was a typo. I've been interested in `create_app` (not `create_all`) function. If your `models.py` import a db, or create instance inside itself, you should try changing lines in `create_app()` to `from .models import User,Player,Game,Match,Team,Post, db as models_db` and `models_db.create_all()` so you'll be creating tables with db from your `models.py`

Comment: You nailed it! The problem was in the initialisation order of `app` and `db`. The `db` I was importing from the base package (and calling `create_all()` on) was not actually the one bound to the models. Hence `create_all()` created nothing.

Comment: Here's  the initialisation sequence that worked for me - comments welcome!__

Comment: I'd be interested in how this works if all your models are not in one file but in a package of multiple files instead.  I have been planning on keeping my models separate for readability.  Does this mean I have to import every db as x_db and then x_db.create_all() on all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_all()` applies to the metadata, that is being discovered by importing modules with models. In your case, models' metadata binds to the `db` from your `models.py` but you are calling `create_all()` from `chessleague/__init__.db` from `create_app()` function, which is different objects for SqlAlchemy. You can fix that by using `db` from `models.py`:

```
from .models import User,Player,Game,Match,Team,Post, db as models_db
models_db.create_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's  the initialisation sequence that worked for me - comments welcome!

My test class `setUp()` calls `create_app(config_name)` from the main app package.
The main app package(`__init__.py`) creates the app instance at module level, ie `app=Flask(my_app_package_name)`
Then my function
`create_app(config_name)`

- loads the right config into app.config (including the right SQLACHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
- imports the model classes and `db` (as `model_db`) from models.py

This import creates the symbol `db` at module level in models.py, followed by the model class definitions:

```
  # models.py
    from . import app
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    ...
    class User(db.Model)
    ... 
    etc
```

Now everything is set up properly: the symbol 'db' can be imported anywhere from models.py, and I can call `db.create_all()` successfully from my test `setUp()`.

@Fian, can you post your solution as an answer so I can give you credit?